# Can't get rid of padding at top of guide without a title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to generate a figure with the guide set into the plotting window. The guide should have a white background and a black borer. I'm mostly successful with this example code...

```
library(ggplot2)

my_data <- data.frame(treatment=rep(c("Treatment A","Treatment B"),50), x=runif(100), y=runif(100))

ggplot(my_data, aes(x, y, color=treatment, shape=treatment)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_manual(values=c('red', 'blue'), name=NULL) +
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,1), name=NULL) + 
    theme(
        legend.background = element_rect(color="black"),
        legend.position=c(0.65, 0.7),
        legend.title = element_blank()
    )
```

It generates a figure that looks like this:
[image]

The problem is that there is extra padding above the line for Treatment A relative to the amount of padding along the bottom of the guid box. I've tried things like `legend.title = element_blank()`, `legend.title = element_text()`, and `legend.title = NULL`, but none of them improve the appearance. Any ideas?

Comment: the github version of ggplot2 provides much more granular control over the spacing (`?theme` to see the additions/changes). I'd suggest trying that if you really need the space removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @hrbrmstr I did some more digging through the documentation and found `legend.margin` and found that if I do `legend.margin = margin(t=0,4,4,4)` that this will make the margins look uniform for this example. The first time through the documentation, I though this theme option referred to the space around the box, not within the box.