# Margins uneven on ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that looks similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:10,each=2),y=runif(20),col=as.factor(rep(1:2,10)))
p <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=col)) +
    geom_line()+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-1,1,0.5),limits=c(-1,1))+
    scale_color_manual(NULL,labels=c("AAAA","BBBB"),values=c("red","blue"))+
    theme(legend.position=c(0.2,0.2))
p
```

[image]
The problem that I have is that the top and bottom margins on the legend are uneven.  There is more space above the "AAAA" than there is below the "BBBB".  Is there a way to fix this?

I've tried `theme(legend.title=element.blank())` and it doesn't help.  I've also tried adjusting `theme(legend.margin=...)` with no luck.  Any help is appreciated, the uneven margins don't look good in the document this is going into.

Comment: You should be able to use `legend.margin` from the development version of ggplot2 to control this.  I tried it out and found you could reduce the top margin by using negative values in `margin`, but am uncertain if that is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873763/cant-get-rid-of-padding-at-top-of-guide-without-a-title) also suggests using `legend.margin`